# How to fix this error and how to grasp the underlying principle of layout in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
    // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: const Positioned(
    left: 100,
    height: 50,
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: Text("111"),
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
  ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
```

I  got a "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget." error in flutter. What leads to this error and how to  grasp the underlying principle of layout in flutter ?

Is there any rules of flutter layout and how to find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message should tell you more and tell you why. It should say something like this:

```
The following ParentDataWidgets are providing parent data to the same RenderObject:
- Positioned(left: 100.0, height: 50.0) (typically placed directly inside a Stack widget)
```

In other words: `Positioned` can only be used in a `Stack` widget. So to fix the error you could wrap it in a `Stack` like this for example

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
      // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
      title: Text('5'),
    ),
    body: const Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          left: 100,
          height: 50,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Text("111"),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: (){},
      tooltip: 'Increment',
      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
    ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
);
```